# Python how to rotate quaternion?

Tags: python

I have the following rotation x, y, z, w (where w is the cosine of half of the rotation angle.):

```
[1,0,0,-8.940696716308594e-08]
```

I want to rotate the following axis coordinates from the following array using the rotation given:

```
[array([[ 0.27050799, -0.027344  , -0.073242  ],
       [ 0.27050799, -0.027344  , -0.073242  ],
       [ 0.45117199, -0.021484  , -0.203125  ],
       [ 0.45117199, -0.021484  , -0.203125  ],
       [ 0.65234399, -0.038086  ,  0.12988301]])]
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? As a starting point, take a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html

Comment: Could you provide example code if you don't mind? I can't seem to figure it out. I had already tried researching it, and I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scipy for this task as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

q = np.array([1,0,0,-8.940696716308594e-08])
rotation = Rotation.from_quat(q)
vectors = np.array(
    [
        [ 0.27050799, -0.027344  , -0.073242  ],
        [ 0.27050799, -0.027344  , -0.073242  ],
        [ 0.45117199, -0.021484  , -0.203125  ],
        [ 0.45117199, -0.021484  , -0.203125  ],
        [ 0.65234399, -0.038086  ,  0.12988301]
    ]
)
rotated_vectors = rotation.apply(vectors)
```